# Can I disable CHANGE event in a custom component?

Tags: apache-flex, events, flash-builder, mxml

I have a custom MXML component which has a change event declared as:

```
<mx:Metadata>
   [Event(name="change", type="flash.events.Event")]
</mx:Metadata>
```

The problem is that this event is dispatched whenever I change ANYTHING inside the component including a simple var.  There are times when I want to be able to change the value of a var in the component without dispatching a change event.  Is there a simple way of disabling the change event and then re-enabling it once I have made the change I want?

I tried to use removeEventListener("change") but it appears I can only do that for a function that has an event listener added.  Same for removeEventListener(Event.CHANGE).

Surely there must be a simple way of disabling events declared in 
    mx:Metadata

Answer (score 0):

yes there are methods on event you can use. So although the event is still dispatched, this gives you complete control of what happens with it.

```
// first set the useCapture flag to true
// this tell flex that onChange gets the event before it starts bubbling
myCustomComponentThatDispatchesALotOfChangeEvents.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onChange, true);

private function onChange(event:Event):void{
    // here is the method you want
    // this stops the event from bubbling and lets you handle
    // all functionality in this listener only
    event.stopImmediatePropogation();
    // now look at what happened and see if you want to 
    // do anything else based on what actually changed
}
```

as a side note, you can also look at Event.preventDefault() which cancel's the events default behavior

"change" is also a flex thing.  It you want to only dispatch the event in one particular scenario, make a new event class that SubClasses Event like MyChangeEvent.  The when you make your change...

```
dispatchEvent(new MyChangeEvent(MyChangeEvent.STUFF_CHANGED))
```

then

```
myCustomComponentThatDispatchesALotOfChangeEvents.addEventListener(MyChangeEvent.STUFF_CHANGED, onChange);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jason.  I'll give it a try and get back to you if I have any questions. Looks promising.